# How can I extract weights labelling edges starting from a fixed set of vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling, trees

Let  `g` be a directed weighted graph (in particular is tree). Given a set of vertices `A`, how can I extract the weights in a set `B` having the following feature

**Each weight in B labels an edge which starts from a vertex in A.**

Being the graph a tree, then a unique edge starts from a vertex. Clearly for a tree, the extraction is conceptually easier. However the extraction procedure seems to be a standard procedure.

For example the graph is

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5}, EdgeWeight -> {0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7}]
```

The subset of vertices is `A={1,3}`. The weight `0.3` is associated with node 1.
The weight `0.4` is associated with node 3.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you post an example of the type of graph in question?

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with visualization? Why did you use that tag?

Comment: I add an example. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Correct grammar would help. I can't make any sense of twisted sentences like "Being the graph a tree then for each vertex starts a unique edge.".

Answer (score 4):

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5}, 
   EdgeWeight -> {0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7}, 
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium, 
   EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"];
A = {1, 3};
```

#### Edges starting at a vertex in `A`:

```
el = EdgeList[g, DirectedEdge[Alternatives @@ A, _]]
```

> {1 -> 2, 3 -> 2}

```
HighlightGraph[g, {A, EdgeList[g, DirectedEdge[Alternatives @@ A, _]]}]
```

[image]

#### Weights of the edges incident to vertices in `A`:

```
PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ EdgeList[g, DirectedEdge[Alternatives @@ A, _]]
```

> {0.3, 0.4}

Comment: Thanks. I mean this.

Comment: I have used this. there is a small problem with this answer.  IncidenceList[g, A]  returns the set of edges which are incident to a vertex in A. Actually in my case, i should have the set  of edges which start from a vertex in A. In the above example the two things coincide because the set A={1,3} contains vertices from which edges start but they do not end in them.  The answer to this post is partial.

Comment: @FrancescoCiardiello, updated method returns the set of edges that start in a vertex in `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean this.

```
Function[edge,
  First[edge] -> PropertyValue[{g, edge}, EdgeWeight]
] /@ EdgeList[g]

{1 -> 0.3, 3 -> 0.4, 2 -> 0.5, 4 -> 0.7}
```